# Get params outside of a component

Tags: react-router

I would like to retrieve the current params outside of a component, and as far as I can tell React Router does not provide a convenient way of doing that.

Sometime back before 0.13 the router had getCurrentParams() which is what I used to use.

Now the best thing I can figure out is:

```
// Copy and past contents of PatternUtils into my project
var PatternUtils = require('<copy of PatternUtils.js>')

const { remainingPathname, paramNames, paramValues } =
   PatternUtils.matchPattern(
       "<copy of path pattern with params I am interested in>",    
   window.location.pathname);
```

Is there a way to do this with React router?

Comment: open github issue here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2547

Answer (score 9):

you could use [matchPath](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/matchPath):

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router'

const { params }= matchPath(window.location.pathname, {
   path: "<copy of path pattern with params I am interested in>"
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `matchPath(window.location.pathname, ...)` within your render function, your component won't signal to be re-rendered on route changes. You can instead use react router's `useLocation` hook to fix this:

```js
import { matchPath } from 'react-router'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

function useParams(path) {
    const { pathname } = useLocation()
    const match = matchPath(pathname, { path })
    return match?.params || {}
}

function MyComponent() {
    const { id } = useParams('/pages/:id')
    return <>Updates on route change: {id}</>
}
```

Note: `matchPath` will return `null` for paths which don't match.
If you use the object destructure pattern `{ params } = matchPath` it may throw the following error:
`Cannot destructure property 'params' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is null.`

Comment: The question specifically asks about how to do this outside of a component. Hooks cannot be used outside of components.